# I don't know how to use xqueries in a html file with an eXist db

Tags: html, xml, database, xquery, exist-db

It's probably really simple but I don't know how to do it. I have these things :

- An HTML file
- An eXist DB with a collection simply containing an XML file with names
- And a very basic xquery file containing the command `count(//name)`

Of course when I execute the xqy file in eXist client it works well, but what I want to do is simply printing in my HTML file this :

> Names in the file : 49 // 49 is the result of the count(//name)

What should I do?

Comment: Is the HTML file stored in exist-db as well or just on disk?

Comment: Well now it's only on disk but I can add it in the exist-db of course. What's the difference ?

Comment: You have to store your XML in the database.  XQuery files can reside on disk or in the database.  If you still have problems, provide your eXist-db version and your method of storing files into the database.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. My XML file is already in the DB, I already have my .xqy file working well with eXist client and generating a HTML source, the problem is just I don't know what to write in a basic HTML file to use this .xqy file there. Considering I have `<p>Names in the file : <!-- what to do here to use .xqy request ?--></p>`.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally in eXist-db (*), XQuery is not embedded in your .html file.  The XQuery file itself assembles your results and serializes them to the browser.  So you might have a .xqy file like this (called via, say, http://yourserver.com:8080/exist/apps/myapp/get-names.xqy):

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html";

let $count := count(//name)
return
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <div><p>There are {$count} names in the database</p></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If you have static snippets of HTML that you want to pull into this file, such as a header, just embed them in the XQuery or call them with the doc() function and insert them as I did with $count above:

```
let $header := doc('/db/myapp/header.html')
```

You can also extend this pattern and develop your own template module to feed your app's content into a template, i.e., template:assemble-page($title, $content) would return a complete HTML page with the $title in the head/title and in body/h1, and the content in the body -- with your static header, footer, etc., as specified in the function.

(*) As of eXist-db 2.0 (which is currently available as a release candidate), there is a new templating framework that lets you embed function calls inside of HTML templates.  It means less mixing/nesting of XQuery and HTML, and a cleaner separation of concerns.  To learn more read this article, [Getting Started with Web Application Development in eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/development-starter.xml).  It's really quite elegant, and I think you might find this preferable to the approach I described above.  In this framework, you would keep your .html file as is and reference the count(//name) routine in the following way:

```
<p>There are <span class="app:count-names"/> names in the database</p>
```

The framework treats the span/@class as a reference to a function, count-names() in a module that you've registered, e.g., /db/apps/myapp/modules/app.xql.  So assuming you've created that module and function, app:count-names(), then when you call the get-names.html page, the database dynamically turns the  element above into the results of app:count-names(), e.g., 42.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hundreds of thank you for you mate, that was perfectly clear and understood :)

Comment: Great to hear, Robin.  Let me also welcome you to join the exist-open mailing list - a great place to ask and see other people's questions, get news about releases, etc.  The subscribe page is at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open, and you can search list archives at http://exist-open.markmail.org.